# inserting a row of data in sql server 2014 in javafx

Tags: java, database, sql-server-2008, javafx, insert

i want to insert a row of data into my USERS table...
this is my code

```javafx
   @FXML
    private void handleRegisterButtonAction() throws SQLException{
        String userName="'"+txt_username.getText()+"'";
        String password="'"+txt_password.getText()+"'";
        String mail="'"+txt_userMail.getText()+"'";
        //for example user id is 22
        int userId=22;

        String insertUser="INSERT INTO USERS(userId,userName,userPassword,userEmail)"
                + " VALUES("+userId+","+userName+","+password+","+mail+");";
        stmt.execute(insertUser);
    }
```

the code runs but table in the database doesn't change

this is because sql doesn't know to apply this query on which database!
But i dont know how to solve this

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the console?

Answer (score 1):

Write query like this :

```
INSERT INTO **Database_Name**.dbo.USERS(userId,userName,userPassword,userEmail)"
                + " VALUES("+userId+","+userName+","+password+","+mail+");";
```

Change **Database_Name** to your database name, then run your code.

Answer (score 1):

First of all use [PreparedStatements](https://www.google.gr/search?q=Java%20PrePARED%20STATEMENT%20TUTORIALS&oq=Java%20PrePARED%20STATEMENT%20TUTORIALS&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.5103j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) because if the userName or password have illegal characters you will have problems with your database .

Example character `'` and boom the insert will not work.

```
PreparedStatement statement  = dataBaseConnection.prepareStatement( INSERT INTO '"+tableName+"' (userId,userName,userPassword,userEmail) VALUES(?,?,?,?)");  

   //Add the data to the table 
   statement.setInt(1,userId); //better to user autoincrement
   statement.setString(2, userName);
   statement.setString(3, password);
   statement.setString(4,userEmail);


   //Execute the update
   statement.executeUpdate();

   //commit in case you have turned autocommit to false
   databaseConnection.commit();
```

**Observe carefully** the statement cause you can see on the table name i have `'` and `'` single column before and after the name of the table.

Comment: @omidXxX My mistakes , i had accidentally added --> ` <--- that symbol instead of `'` on the code which was obviously wrong . I corrected it now.